# changing class property value outside of the class

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class say `ConstructionSet` which is having name property having computed inside get method like as below

```
public class ConstructionSet
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            string climateZonesCsv = (ClimateZones != null && ClimateZones.Any())
                ? $" - {string.Join(", ", ClimateZones.Select(a => a.Name))}"
                : "";
            var sourceOfData = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceOfData?.Edition)
                ? $"{SourceOfData.Name}, {SourceOfData.Edition}"
                : SourceOfData?.Name;
            return $"{sourceOfData} - {ConstructionMassingType?.Name}{climateZonesCsv}";
        }
        set { }
    }
    .......
    .......
}
```

and then I am doing some operations like cloning this `ConstructionSet` object and appending some text like "copy" to the name property of `ConstructionSet` after deepclone and it is looks like as below

```
 var targetDhpConstructionSets = sourceDhpConstructionSets.ConvertAll(
                dhpcs =>
                {
                    var newDhpConstructionSet = new DesignHubProjectConstructionSet(dhpcs);
                    var clone = DeepCloner.Clone(dhpcs.SectionObjectRaw);
                    clone.Name += " (Copy)";
                    newDhpConstructionSet.AddPatch(employeeContext, clone);
                    newDhpConstructionSet.IsDefault = dhpcs.IsDefault;
                    newDhpConstructionSet.Warnings = dhpcs.Warnings;
                    return newDhpConstructionSet;
                });
```

and below is the image where it shows `dhpcs.SectionObjectRaw` is indeed a `ConstructionSet` class object and if i observe the `clone object` name property value after this line `clone.Name += " (Copy)";` the `Copy` text is not appended.

[image]

Could any one please let me know why i am not seeing the appended values to the name property of `ConstructionSet`

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because your setter does literally nothing:

```
set { }
```

Since your getter obtains several pieces of information on-the-fly, it's not obvious how to change your design to add on arbitrary text to what the getter provides. You could have a "suffix" property that gets appended to the strings that are currently returned, for example.  Or have a backing field that the getter populates if it is null, then have the setter change the value of the backing field.

Based on your comments I would probably go with a backing field:

```
private string _Name;
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        if(this._Name == null) {
            string climateZonesCsv = (ClimateZones != null && ClimateZones.Any())
                ? $" - {string.Join(", ", ClimateZones.Select(a => a.Name))}"    
                : "";
            var sourceOfData = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceOfData?.Edition)
                ? $"{SourceOfData.Name}, {SourceOfData.Edition}"
                : SourceOfData?.Name;
            _Name = $"{sourceOfData} - {ConstructionMassingType?.Name}{climateZonesCsv}";
        }
        return _Name
    }
    set { _Name = value }
}
```

Comment: yeah thanks for the insight, I need to append that text `Copy` only in particular case to this text `$"{sourceOfData} - {ConstructionMassingType?.Name}{climateZonesCsv}"`  in all other cases it is same that is returned by get method